# Get first letter of a string from column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm fighting with pandas and for now I'm loosing. I have source table similar to this:

```
import pandas as pd

a=pd.Series([123,22,32,453,45,453,56])
b=pd.Series([234,4353,355,453,345,453,56])
df=pd.concat([a, b], axis=1)
df.columns=['First', 'Second']
```

I would like to add new column to this data frame with first digit from values in column 'First':
a) change number to string from column 'First'
b) extracting first character from newly created string
c) Results from b save as new column in data frame

I don't know how to apply this to the pandas data frame object. I would be grateful for helping me with that.

Comment: Can you show your desired output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas make new column from string slice of another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25789445/pandas-make-new-column-from-string-slice-of-another-column)

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Cast the `dtype` of the col to `str` and you can perform vectorised slicing calling `str`:

```
In [29]:
df['new_col'] = df['First'].astype(str).str[0]
df

Out[29]:
   First  Second new_col
0    123     234       1
1     22    4353       2
2     32     355       3
3    453     453       4
4     45     345       4
5    453     453       4
6     56      56       5
```

if you need to you can cast the `dtype` back again calling `astype(int)` on the column

Comment: For large arrays casting to string is not the fastest: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13547396/5276797

Comment: @IanS true if the digit length was fixed then a `floordiv` would work better here

Answer (score 28):

#### `.str.get`

This is the simplest to specify string methods

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['xyz', 'abc', 'foobar'], 'B': [123, 456, 789]})
df

        A    B
0     xyz  123
1     abc  456
2  foobar  789

df.dtypes

A    object
B     int64
dtype: object
```

For string (read:`object`) type columns, use

```
df['C'] = df['A'].str[0]
# Similar to,
df['C'] = df['A'].str.get(0)
```

`.str` handles NaNs by returning NaN as the output.

For non-numeric columns, an `.astype` conversion is required beforehand, as shown in @Ed Chum's answer.

```
# Note that this won't work well if the data has NaNs. 
# It'll return lowercase "n"
df['D'] = df['B'].astype(str).str[0]
```

```
df
        A    B  C  D
0     xyz  123  x  1
1     abc  456  a  4
2  foobar  789  f  7
```

---

#### List Comprehension and Indexing

There is [enough evidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54028199/for-loops-with-pandas-when-should-i-care) to suggest a simple list comprehension will work well here and probably be faster.

```
# For string columns
df['C'] = [x[0] for x in df['A']]

# For numeric columns
df['D'] = [str(x)[0] for x in df['B']]
```

```
df
        A    B  C  D
0     xyz  123  x  1
1     abc  456  a  4
2  foobar  789  f  7
```

If your data has NaNs, then you will need to handle this appropriately with an `if`/`else` in the list comprehension,

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['xyz', np.nan, 'foobar'], 'B': [123, 456, np.nan]})
df2

        A      B
0     xyz  123.0
1     NaN  456.0
2  foobar    NaN

# For string columns
df2['C'] = [x[0] if isinstance(x, str) else np.nan for x in df2['A']]

# For numeric columns
df2['D'] = [str(x)[0] if pd.notna(x) else np.nan for x in df2['B']]

        A      B    C    D
0     xyz  123.0    x    1
1     NaN  456.0  NaN    4
2  foobar    NaN    f  NaN
```

---

Let's do some timeit tests on some larger data.

```
df_ = df.copy()
df = pd.concat([df_] * 5000, ignore_index=True) 

%timeit df.assign(C=df['A'].str[0])
%timeit df.assign(D=df['B'].astype(str).str[0])

%timeit df.assign(C=[x[0] for x in df['A']])
%timeit df.assign(D=[str(x)[0] for x in df['B']])
```

```
12 ms ± 253 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
27.1 ms ± 1.38 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

3.77 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
7.84 ms ± 145 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

List comprehensions are 4x faster.