# Dataframe content subsetting using lambda apply using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, lambda, apply

I am fairly new to python and pandas and I am trying to do the following:

Here is my dataset:

```
df5
Out[52]: 
      NAME
0  JIMMcdonald
1   TomDickson
2    SamHarper
```

I am trying to extract the first three characters using lambda apply

Here is what I have tried:

```
df5["FirstName"] = df5.apply(lambda x: x[0:3],axis=1)
```

here is the result:

```
df5
Out[54]: 
          NAME    FirstName
0  JIMMcdonald  JIMMcdonald
1   TomDickson   TomDickson
2    SamHarper    SamHarper
```

I dont understand why it didnt work.. can someone help me?

Thank you

Comment: You don't need apply for easy operations, use: `df['NAME'].str[:3]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get first letter of a string from column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552874/get-first-letter-of-a-string-from-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the difference between [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) (which is what you're using) and [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) (which is what you want to use). The easiest way to fix this is to select the series you want from your dataframe, and use `.apply` on that:

```
df5["FirstName"] = df5["NAME"].apply(lambda x: x[0:3],axis=1)
```

Your current code is running the apply function *once* on *each column*, in which case it's selecting the first three rows. This fixed code is running the function on *each value in the selected column*.

Better, yet, as @Erfan pointed out in his comment, doing simple one-liner string operations like this can often be simplified using panda's `.str`, which allows you to operate on entire series of strings in much the same way you'd operate on a single string:

```
df5["FirstName"] = df5["NAME"].str[:3]
```