# Optimizing code pandas dataframe extracting subvalue

Tags: python, pandas

I need to optimize this code part which takes dozens of seconds with a big dataset .

```
        if ((isnan(data["x"][i]))==False):
            data["Visibility"][i]=int(data["Visibility"][i][0:2]) # Extract the first two numbers 
        else:
            data["x"][i]=1000 # Replace null values with 1000
```

Editing: For my dataset, I have string column values and I want to replace them with subsets of same values

Here is an example :

"01 : visibilité horizontale 0.1km"  --> 01

"02 : visibilité horizontale 0.2km" --> 02

"03 : visibilité horizontale 0.3km" -- > 03

...

Comment: Can you show a bit more ? Also, it looks like you're iterating over a dataframe. That's extremely slow and very rarely (if ever) the solution.

Comment: If all you want to do is replace the NaNs or missing values in a dataframe, look at the [fillna function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) which should do it much more efficiently than iterating over the dataframe

Comment: Please include a _small_ subset of your data as a __copyable__ piece of code that can be used for testing as well as your expected output for the __provided__ data. See  [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible, Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/15497888).

Comment: And just a side note - no need to ever compare to `True` or `False` in `if` statements. you can (and should) do something like `if not isnan(data["x"][i])):`

Comment: I added some clarification to my question ..

Answer (score 0):

What's slowing you down is for-looping over the data frame, instead of using built in functions.

WITHOUT A FOR LOOP:

```
data.loc[~isnan(data["x"]), "Visibility"] = data.loc[~isnan(data["x"]), "Visibility"].str[:2]
data.loc[isnan(data["x"]), "Visibility"] = 1000
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35552874/get-first-letter-of-a-string-from-column)

---

above code is untested, as you provided no reproducible example.